# How to solve the error "cp: cannot create regular file : No such file or directory" in centos7

Tags: linux, centos, file-copy

I tried to copy my WRF output files to the `/run/media/maslab-3/exthdd/` directory where my 8 TB external HDD is mounted. But, it is not copying; rather, the following error is throwing:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/run/media/maslab-3/exthdd/wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00:00:00’: No such file or directory
```

I searched online and thought that it could be related to permission problem. So, I tried `chmod -R 777 /run/media/maslab-3/exthdd/`, `chmod -R 755 /run/media/maslab-3/exthdd/` and `chmod -R 766 /run/media/maslab-3/exthdd/`. But none of this worked. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to solve this issue? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that NTFS or FAT or something? If so, the colons are likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: When I renamed the file by replacing the ':' with '_' , it worked. Thank you so much @muru.